# Optimise object overlapping detection (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, optimization, collision-detection

### Issue

I am writing a program which involves calculating how many pixels one moving object overlaps the other. I'd have to return this value many times a second, so the program would have to be efficient. The example that I have come up with seems not to be.

---

### Example

Let's scale-down for a minute and imagine we have an object that is 3*3 pixels and one that is 3*2

```
a b c
d e f   j k l
g h i   m n o
```

Each letter represents an individual pixel of each object. The 3*3 object sits on the left, and the 3*2 object sits on the right, with an x value 4 greater than that of the larger object. They are not overlapping.

---

### Code

Currently, I am returning the number of overlapping pixels through a simple function that checks every pixel in object one against every pixel in object two for overlaps:

```
var a = {
    width: 3,
    height: 3,
    x: 0,
    y: 0
}

var b = {
    width: 3,
    height: 2,
    x: 4,
    y: 0
}

function overlappingPixels(object_1, object_2) {
    var overlapping = 0;
    for (var w_1 = 0; w_1 < object_1.width; w_1++) {
        for (var h_1 = 0; h_1 < object_1.height; h_1++) {
            for (var w_2 = 0; w_2 < object_1.width; w_2++) {
                for (var h_2 = 0; h_2 < object_1.height; h_2++) {
                    if (w_1 + object_1.x == w_2 + object_2.x && h_1 + object_1.y == h_2 + + object_2.y) {
                        overlapping++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return overlapping;
}
```

`overlappingPixels(a, b);` returns 0, because the two objects have no overlapping pixels.

---

### Recap

To recap, I have built a function that compares each pixel of object one to each pixel of object two for any overlaps. This *seems* horribly inefficient, and I was curious as to whether there was a quicker option if this calculation needed to be performed very quickly for moving objects. The speed of the function breaks down quickly as the size of the objects increase. I'd be performing this calculation on larger objects anyway, so this isn't ideal.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to see how much of an overlap there is or just want to know if two objects at all with a function that return true or false?

Comment: Are your objects always rectangles? Then it's indeed grossly inefficient to loop through all pixels. Do some geometry to calculate the intersection area of two rectangles in constant time.

Comment: @Ozan I need to return the number of overlapping pixels.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, the objects are always rectangles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easy and efficient way to check if two rectangles collide.

```
var rect1 = {x: 5, y: 5, width: 50, height: 50}
var rect2 = {x: 20, y: 10, width: 10, height: 10}

if (rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.width &&
   rect1.x + rect1.width > rect2.x &&
   rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.height &&
   rect1.height + rect1.y > rect2.y) {
    // collision detected!
}
```

See [MDN 2D object collision detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection)

---

To get the size of overlap is also quite easy once you know there is collision for sure. Just get the heigth and width where they overlap, and get the area by multiplying them. See the `calculateCollisionLength` function in the snippet to see how you can calculate the overlap without going over it pixel by pixel.

```js
const calculateCollisionLength = (point1, point2, length1, length2) => {
    const pointb1 = point1 + length1;
    const pointb2 = point2 + length2;
    const diff1 = Math.abs(point1 - point2);
    const diff2 = Math.abs(pointb1 - pointb2);
    return (length1 + length2 - diff1 - diff2) / 2;
}
function checkCollusion(rect1, rect2) {
    if (rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.width &&
        rect1.x + rect1.width > rect2.x &&
        rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.height &&
        rect1.height + rect1.y > rect2.y) {
        // collision detected!

        const collision = { xLength: 0, yLength: 0 };

        collision.xLength = calculateCollisionLength(rect1.x, rect2.x, rect1.width, rect2.width);
        collision.yLength = calculateCollisionLength(rect1.y, rect2.y, rect1.height, rect2.height);

        return collision.xLength * collision.yLength;
    }
    else return null;
}

var rect1 = { x: 5, y: 5, width: 50, height: 50 }
var rect2 = { x: 20, y: 10, width: 10, height: 10 }
console.log(checkCollusion(rect1, rect2))
```

Comment: This doesn't return the number of pixels that overlap, though.

Comment: You can use it to efficiently check for collision and calculate the overlap if there is a collision.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @CasparB, I added a snippet to show how you can calculate the values without inefficiently iterating over the pixels.